# Put lattice deform operation in a custom menu

Tags: python, scripting

I created a menu class and now filling the menu with operations,But when I tried to use the lattice deform operation it didn't show up,

Here is the script I used:

```
layout.operator("object.parent_set(type='LATTICE')")
```

But as I said,it never show up in the menu,while other operations appear normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass arguments to operators via the layout.

```
op = layout.operator("object.parent_set")
op.type = 'LATTICE'
```

can also use

```
layout.operator("blah.blah").prop = value
```

I prefer the former stylewise.

Comment: What language is this? Is it Python or Opengl?